# how can i make my linux vibrant?

Tags: screen, colors

I used everything to change my display color settings. I didn't tried any software like vibrant-cli and vibrantLinux because I am new to Linux. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask, and then edit your question to try to ask a clear, answerable question.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "vibrant" by [edit]ing your Question.  Do Not reply via Comment.